# List of objects is null when posting to MVC action when using for loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have posted a list of objects to an MVC action just fine in the past but I am not sure why I am getting null results on the occasion.

I have created a custom view-model:

```
public class CustomPmScheduleGenerator
{
    public bool Save { get; set; }
    public bool Search { get; set; }
    public DateTime? BegDueDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDateDate { get; set; }
    public string GenSn { get; set; }
    public string PmName { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public IList<stp_GetPmSchedulesGenerator_Result> Pms { get; set; }
    public IList<stp_GetRepairSchedulesGenerator_Result> Repairs { get; set; } 
}
```

The above object is what I am posting to the index action. Both Pms and Repairs are coming back as null.

Here is my actions (GET and POST):

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new CustomPmScheduleGenerator();

        var pms = _db.stp_GetPmSchedulesGenerator(null, null, Convert.ToInt32(Session["CustomerNumber"]), null, null).ToList();
        var repairs = _db.stp_GetRepairSchedulesGenerator(null, null, Convert.ToInt32(Session["CustomerNumber"]), null, null).ToList();

        model.Pms = pms;
        model.Repairs = repairs;

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(CustomPmScheduleGenerator model)
    {
        if (model.Save)
        {
            //Update the PMs
            foreach (var pm in model.Pms)
            {
                //TODO: Update the current PM
            }

            //Update the Repairs
            foreach (var repair in model.Repairs)
            {
                //TODO: Update the Current Repair
            }
        }
        else if (model.Search)
        {
            var pms = _db.stp_GetPmSchedulesGenerator(model.BegDueDate, model.EndDateDate, Convert.ToInt32(Session["CustomerNumber"]),model.PmName, model.GenSn).ToList();

            var repairs = _db.stp_GetRepairSchedulesGenerator(null, null, Convert.ToInt32(Session["CustomerNumber"]), null, null).ToList();

            model.Pms = pms;
            model.Repairs = repairs;

            return View(model);
        }

        return View();
    }
```

I have put a break point on the POST action on the if statement line and check the values of the parameter "model" and that is where I am seeing the null values.

Here is what my view looks like:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "PmScheduleGenerator", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div>
        <h1>
            <strong>PM Schedule</strong>
            @Html.ActionLink("Add Repair", "AddRepair", null, new { @class = "btn btn-warning", @style = "float:right;margin-left:5px;" })
            @Html.ActionLink("Save", "AddRepair", null, new { @class = "btn btn-success", @style = "float:right" })
        </h1>
    </div>
    <hr />


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 form-group">
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.Label("Due Beg. Date")
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <div class="input-group date">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BegDueDate, null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 form-group">
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.Label("Due End Date")
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <div class="input-group date">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EndDateDate, null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 form-group">
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.Label("Gen S/N")
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <div class="input-group">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.GenSn, DropdownLists.GetGenSns(Convert.ToInt32(Session["CustomerNumber"]), Session["PmType"].ToString(), Session["Whse"].ToString()), new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 form-group">
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.Label("PM Name")
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <div class="input-group">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PmName, DropdownLists.GetPmNames(Convert.ToInt32(Session["CustomerNumber"]), Session["PmType"].ToString(), Session["Whse"].ToString()), new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 form-group">
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.Label("Type")
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <div class="input-group">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Type, DropdownLists.GetTypes(), new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 form-group">
            <div class="editor-label">
                &nbsp;
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-success" />
                <input type="submit" value="Clear" class="btn btn-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Gen S/N</th>
                <th>Loc ID</th>
                <th style="width: 140px;">PM Description</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>Next PM Due Dt.</th>
                <th>Sched Arrival Dt.</th>
                <th style="width: 160px;">Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Pms.Count; i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Pms[i].FleetTruckNo)
                        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Pms[i].FleetTruckNo)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Pms[i].LocationID)
                        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Pms[i].LocationID)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Pms[i].Description)
                        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Pms[i].Description)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Pms[i].City)
                        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Pms[i].City)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="editor-field">
                            <div class="input-group date">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Pms[i].NextPMDueDt, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control" })
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="editor-field">
                            <div class="input-group date">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Pms[i].EstArrivalDt, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control" })
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="hidden" class="query" value="?customerNumber=@Model.Pms[i].CustNo&fleetTruckNo=@Model.Pms[i].FleetTruckNo&sro=@Model.Pms[i].RepairOrdNo&scheduleId=@Model.Pms[i].ScheduleID" />
                        <input type="button" class="comments btn btn-primary" value="Comments" />
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Process" />
                    </td>
                </tr>

            }
            @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Repairs.Count; i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Repairs[i].FleetTruckNo)
                        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Repairs[i].FleetTruckNo)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Repairs[i].LocationID)
                        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Repairs[i].LocationID)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Repairs[i].Description)
                        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Repairs[i].Description)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Repairs[i].City)
                        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Repairs[i].City)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        N/A
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="editor-field">
                            <div class="input-group date">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Repairs[i].ScheduledDt, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control" })
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="hidden" class="query" value="?customerNumber=@Model.Repairs[i].CustNo&fleetTruckNo=@Model.Repairs[i].FleetTruckNo&sro=@Model.Repairs[i].SRO&scheduleId=@Model.Repairs[i].ScheduleID&repair=true" />
                        <input type="button" class="comments btn btn-primary" value="Comments" />
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Process" />
                    </td>
                </tr>

            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

As you can see in the view I have two for loops going throw Repairs and PMs. Does anyone know why I am getting null values in the POST Action?

Comment: What do your other classes look like? (e.g. `stp_GetPmSchedulesGenerator_Result`). Is it possible the model binder isn't able to instantiate them? (no public parameterless constructor, e.g.?)

Comment: There is nothing in the code you have shown to indicate it would not bind. But you have included a whole lot of hidden inputs which is just crazy (particularly  as a comment below indicates you have at least 173 items in the collection. This will degrade performance (sending a whole lot of extra html and sending it back again unchanged) an open you to over-posting attacks. Just include the properties you edit and get the original items in the POST method.

Comment: But you have 2 hidden inputs which make don't make sense - `<input type="hidden" class="query" value="?customerNumber=@Model.Pms[i].CustNo&.../>` They don't have a name attribute so wont post back so I'm guessing you have some javascript/jquery associated with the form. If you are posting using ajax, then you need to show your scripts.

Comment: Stephen im not using ajax. Based on the code that I provided...it clearly shows that I am not using ajax to post the data.

Comment: Then what are the `<input type="hidden" class="query" ..` inputs for and the buttons for `Comments` and `Process`? - obviously they don't do anything without javascript. The code as you have shown will work fine

Answer (score 1):

add this to you model constructor and see if it helps.

```
public class CustomPmScheduleGenerator
{
    public CustomPmScheduleGenerator()
    {
        Pms = new List<stp_GetPmSchedulesGenerator_Result>();
        Repairs = new List<stp_GetRepairSchedulesGenerator_Result>();
    }

    public bool Save { get; set; }
    etc..
    public IList<stp_GetPmSchedulesGenerator_Result> Pms { get; set; }
    public IList<stp_GetRepairSchedulesGenerator_Result> Repairs { get; set; } 
}
```

Model binder can create a new instance of your model but the Pms and Repairs objects are null, unless in instantiate them in the constructor

Comment: I tried adding the constructor but still getting null values.

Comment: here is a short version of what you're doing and it seems to post back the data fine.  https://dotnetfiddle.net/2FAkKi

Comment: Ya, I just tried yours out and it definitely seems to be working fine. I also tried it without the constructor and it seems to be workings. Do you know anything else that I can check? I compared my code and it is exactly the same....

Comment: you're going to need to use fidder or something to see what values are getting posted back and see if the Pms and Repairs fields are getting passed to your controller..

Comment: When I use fiddler and look at the data being passed. I have the field names Repairs[173].FleetTruckNo, Repairs[173].LocationID, Pms[2].FleetTruckNo....etc. Values are being passed too.

Comment: @JamieD77, The `DefaultModelBinder` initializes the collections so adding a constructor to initialize them is not necessary.

Comment: @StephenMuecke yeah i noticed its doing that now.. i had issues with that back in mvc3 so maybe it has changed??  i still just do it anyway..

Comment: @user3788671  do you have values  for Repairs 0 - 173? or 0 thru whatever number of repairs you're showing?

Comment: @JamieD77 I only have the values for the repairs that I am showing in the table when Posting. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I'm just trying to make sure you have a value for every item starting from 0... i you have Repairs[0].FleetTruckNo and Repairs[1].FleetTruckNo you should get a list in your controller.. if you just have Repairs[1].FleetTruckNo and no 0 then your Repairs list will be null..

Comment: Oh okay, well the numbers jump all over the place. So currently there is no Repairs[0]. It goes Repairs[173], Repairs[57], Repairs[58], Repairs[90]. Should I try putting them in two different tables. Why are they not going in order based on the i value?

Answer (score -1):

put your **for** under a **if** statement

```
if(Model.Pms != null){
  for...
}
```

Comment: I don't think this makes sense because Count will never be null. It will be 0 if anything. I think i got what you were going for and  it did not work unfortunately. I checked to see if the Model.Pms != null && Model.Pms.Count > 0